# We want to get the posixpath for Mac in Python... Is there any way to get this

Tags: python

Suppose my file is on the Desktop:

I want the path as `/MAC OS X 10.7 US/Users/labuser/Desktop/abcd.txt`

When I am using any function to get the path, I get the path as: `/Users/labuser/Desktop/abcd.txt`

Is there any way to get the path with the drive name?

Comment: "/Users/labuser/Desktop/abcd.txt" is the posix path. Perhaps what you want is the HFS path?

Comment: The drive name is never a part of the path, ever, except on Windows. Why do you want this?

Comment: @jathanism, the drive name is part of the path in HFS (filesystem for Mac).

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this on a Mac. Mounted volumes are found in `/Volumes`. On my MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.7.2, this is what I see:

```
% ls -l /Volumes
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwt+  5 root   admin   170 Nov 21 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  38 root   wheel  1.4K Nov 21 20:40 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin     1 Nov  6 20:49 Macintosh HD -> /
```

There you see a symlink named "Macintosh HD" (or whatever you named it) that links to `/`.  So in the case `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is equivalent to `/`.

Now, it sounds like what you want the HFS path, which is colon-separated (e.g. `Macintosh HD:Users:labuser:Desktop:abcd.txt`)? In that case, I don't know of a current Python implementation to do it, but there is an [AppleScript command you may run on your Mac to convert HFS Path to POSIX](http://macosx.com/forums/1419319-post2.html) and vice versa:

```
% osascript -e 'return POSIX path of file "Macintosh HD:Users:labuser:Desktop:abcd.txt"'
/Users/labuser/Desktop/abcd.txt
```

And the reverse:

```
% osascript -e 'return posix file "/Users/labuser/Desktop/abcd.txt"'
file Macintosh HD:Users:labuser:Desktop:abcd.txt
```

It's not the greatest, but it would be trivial to turn this into a helper function.

**Edit:** I found this extremely advanced [Pure Python™ implementation](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2005-April/013777.html) leveraging PyObjC API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [macpath](http://docs.python.org/library/macpath.html#module-macpath) module ?

It contains all the os.path methods but in a  Macintosh pathnames style.

Comment: According to the docstring for `macpath.splitdrive`: "on the Mac, the drive is always empty".